# Android - How to display images from URL in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview, android-image

I have searched and tried a lot of different methods to display images from URL in a ListView but I can't get my code to work. Below is my code to download images and then display them in a ListView but somehow it is not working.

```
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
             return null;
        }
    }
```

And here is my code to call the above function

```
Drawable image = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://10.0.0.5/images/logo.jpg");
```

After this I put it into a Map and then put the Map into a ArrayList called "productsList"

```
map.put("avatar", image);
productsList.add(map);
```

And finally I show the HashMap in a ListView with SimpleAdapter

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
   Home.this, productsList, 
   R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
   TAG_NAME, "url", "avatar"},
   new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.url, R.id.avatar });
```

My app shows everything except for the images. I have searched on Google for this problem but couldn't get any help. Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Did you verify that LoadImageFromWebOperations does not return null?

Comment: @Nobu Yes, I printed the result in TextView and it gave something like _android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@2bf022d0_.

Answer (score 1):

```
try

if (image != null) {

                Bitmap bitimage = null;
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 1;
                try {

                                           //bitimage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(data.getThumbnail().toString().trim().toString()).getContent(), null, options);
                                            bitimage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(ed).getContent(), null, options);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitimage);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will definitely help you,**

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(Home.this, productsList, R.layout.list_item,
new String[] { TAG_PID,TAG_NAME, "url", "avatar"},
 new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.url, R.id.avatar });
```

Create a CustomAdapter class which extends SimpleAdapter, override the getView() method,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) super.getItem(position);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.yourImageID);
    TextView txt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.yourtxtID1);
    TextView txt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.yourtxtID2);
    TextView txt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.yourtxtID3);


    image.setImageDrawable((Drawable) hm.get("avatar"));
    txt1.setText(hm.get("TAG_PID").toString());
    txt2.setText(hm.get("TAG_NAME").toString());
    txt3.setText(hm.get("url").toString());

    return v;

}
```

Let me know if the problem still persists..